# RegEx for retrieving words from a dictionary

Tags: regex, python-3.x, dictionary, findall, dictionary-comprehension

here is my code : It looks in one dictionary and in another one and calculate the score of the values of the first dictionary.

```
d_score = {k: [0, 0, 0] for k in d_filtered_words.keys()}
for k, v in d_filtered_words.items():
    for word in v:
        if word in dico_lexique:
            print(word, dico_lexique[word]
            d_score[k] = [a + b for a, b in zip(map(int, dico_lexique[word]), d_score[k])]
d_score = {k: list(map(str, v)) for k, v in d_score.items()}
```

The result of the print is :

```
avoir ['101', '3772', '110']
serrer ['175', '936', '252']
main ['251', '2166', '49']
avoir ['101', '3772', '110']
serrer ['175', '936', '252']
enfant ['928', '1274', '19']
aérien ['354', '769', '39']
affable ['486', '45', '32']
affaire ['46', '496', '104']
agent ['265', '510', '18']
connaître ['448', '293', '29']
rien ['24', '185', '818']
trouver ['387', '198', '31']
être ['225', '328', '44']
emmerder ['0', '23', '493']
rien ['24', '185', '818']
suffire ['420', '35', '56']
mettre ['86', '1299', '67']
multiprise ['314', '71', '0']
abasourdir ['0', '43', '393']
ablation ['75', '99', '353']
abominable ['0', '24', '1170']
être ['225', '328', '44']
seul ['65', '97', '540']
ami ['492', '72', '31']
aimer ['1140', '49', '35']
```

Just to clarify : 
The dico_lexique also contains key_word like :

```
sabot de Vénus>orchidée;294;76;0
imbuvable>boisson;0;0;509
imbuvable>insupportable;0;0;416
accentuer>intensifier;255;89;4
accentuer>mettre un accent;50;29;30
```

And these are the words i woulk like also to take into consideration when looking at the keys in the dico_lexique

The result of d_score is  :

```
{'15': ['1731', '12856', '792'], '44': ['3079', '4437', '2549'], '45': ['75', '166', '1916'], '47': ['7721', '3854', '7259']}
```

Hello, Just to clarify the word containing the element '>' are also part of the dico_lexique, they are not from another file. In the dico_lexique, you have different sens of a word and to differentiate it some are follows by '>'. I am looking only in the dico_lexique and the d_filtered and would want to take into consideration key_word follow by '>' so that when i see the 'serrer' in d_filtered_words , the code would retrieve the values of 'serrer' and also all the value of the word "serrer" follow by '>'.

```
d_score = {k: [0, 0, 0] for k in d_filtered_words.keys()}
for k, v in d_filtered_words.items():
    for word in v:
        regex =????
        if word in dico_lexique and if word = re.findall(regex, word)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT: new version after you updated the problem.**

Sample data is now:

```
>>> d_filtered_words = {
...    '1': ['avoir', 'main'],
...    '2': ['main', 'serrer', 'posséder'],
... }

>>> dico_lexique = {
...     'avoir': ('101', '3772', '110'),
...     'avoir>posséder': ('91', '2724', '108'),
...     'serrer': ('175', '936', '252'),
...     'main': ('251', '2166', '49'),
... }
```

You have to process `dico_lexique` first to remove the parts after the `>` and group the values by main word:

```
>>> values_by_word = {}
>>> for word, values in dico_lexique.items():
...     main, *_ = word.split(">")
...     values_by_word.setdefault(main, []).append(values)
>>> values_by_word
{'avoir': [('101', '3772', '110'), ('91', '2724', '108')], 'serrer': [('175', '936', '252')], 'main': [('251', '2166', '49')]}
```

Explanation:

- `main, *_ = word.split(">")` keeps everything before an optional `>` and forget the rest (see [destructuring assignement](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/))
- `setdefault` creates a new list associated with the main word if it doesn't exist and add the values.

Now, same logic as below:

```
>>> def merge_values(tuples):
...     """Sums columns (with a str->int->str conversion)"""
...     return tuple(str(sum(int(v) for v in vs)) for vs in zip(*tuples))

>>> merged_values_by_word = {code:merge_values(tuples) for code, tuples in values_by_word.items()}
>>> merged_values_by_word
{'avoir': ('192', '6496', '218'), 'serrer': ('175', '936', '252'), 'main': ('251', '2166', '49')}
```

(I renamed `get_values` to `merge_values` but it is the same function.)
You can use the code below with `merged_values_by_word` instead of `dico_lexique`.

**End of edit: old version below, for the record**

Your mixing two problems: what your code does (summing values associated with words or family of words) and parsing a file or a string.

## Some code review

Let me summarize:
* you have `dico_lexique` that maps a word to three values (strings containing integers)
* you have `d_filtered_words` that maps a code ('15', '44', ...) to a list of words.
* you create a dict that maps the code to `[sum of the value1, sum of the value2, sum of the value2]` for every word that is mapped to the code and is present in `dico_lexique`.

First, if you have always three values, use a `tuple`, not a `list`. I'll use this custom sample:

```
>>> d_filtered_words = {
...    '1': ['avoir', 'main'],
...    '2': ['main', 'serrer', 'posséder'],
... }

>>> dico_lexique = {
...     'avoir': ('101', '3772', '110'),
...     'serrer': ('175', '936', '252'),
...     'main': ('251', '2166', '49'),
...     # no posséder here
... }
```

Second, build a dict that maps the code to the list of three values:

```
>>> def get_tuples(words):
...     """return the tuples of values for every word in dico_lexique"""
...     return [dico_lexique[word] for word in words if word in dico_lexique]

>>> tuples_by_code = {code:get_tuples(words) for code, words in  d_filtered_words.items()}
>>> tuples_by_code
{'1': [('101', '3772', '110'), ('251', '2166', '49')], '2': [('251', '2166', '49'), ('175', '936', '252')]}
```

Third, sum the values "by column". There is an easy way to do it:

```
>>> tuples = [(1,2,3), (4,5,6)]
>>> tuple(zip(*tuples))
((1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6))
>>> tuple(map(sum, zip(*tuples)))
(5, 7, 9)
```

The `zip` function will group the first element of every tuple, then the second element of every tuple, then...: you get the "columns" and just have to sum them. In your case:

```
>>> def get_values(tuples):
...     """Sums columns (with a str->int->str conversion)"""
...     return tuple(str(sum(int(v) for v in vs)) for vs in zip(*tuples))

>>> values_by_code = {code:get_values(tuples) for code, tuples in tuples_by_code.items()}
>>> values_by_code
{'1': ('352', '5938', '159'), '2': ('426', '3102', '301')}
```

## Your question

Now your question. Imagine I have a text file with the alternative forms:

```
>>> text = """avoir>posséder
... voilé>dissimulé
... voilé>caché"""
```

You have to parse that file and to split every line on `>` to build a dict `alternative -> main`:

```
>>> main_by_alternative = {a: m for line in text.split("\\n") for m, a in [line.split(">")]}
>>> main_by_alternative
{'posséder': 'avoir', 'dissimulé': 'voilé', 'caché': 'voilé'}
```

The key idea is to split the line on the char `>` to get the main form and the alternative form in a list. `for m, a in [line.split(">")]` is a trick to have `m, a = line.split(">")` in a dict comprehension. Now, back to `get_tuples`:

```
>>> def get_tuples(words):
...     """return the tuples of values for every word in dico_lexique"""
...     return [dico_lexique[main_by_alternative.get(word, word)] for word in words if main_by_alternative.get(word, word) in dico_lexique]
```

What's new? Look at: `main_by_alternative.get(word, word)`. It simply gets the main form if it exits, or the word itself else.

```
>>> {code:get_tuples(words) for code, words in  d_filtered_words.items()}
{'1': [('101', '3772', '110'), ('251', '2166', '49')], '2': [('251', '2166', '49'), ('175', '936', '252'), ('101', '3772', '110')]}
```

The code `2` is now mapped to the three words: 'main', 'serrer', 'avoir' (via 'posséder').

Hope it helps. I used a lot of dict/list comprehensions to make it short, but if you need, do not hesitate to expand the code into regular loops.

Comment: Hello, Just to clarify the word containing the element '>' are also part of the dico_lexique, they are not from another file. In the dico_lexique, you have different sens of a word and to differentiate it some are follows by '>'.  I am looking only in the dico_lexique and the d_filtered and would want to take into consideration key_word follow by '>' so that when i see the 'serrer' in d_filtered_words , the code would retrieve the values of 'serrer' and also all the value of the word "serrer" follow by '>'.

Comment: @kely789456123 Updated the answer.

Comment: i have this error  import TreeTagger OK
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CSV_dico_2.py", line 87, in <module>
    merged_values_by_word = {code:merge_values(tuples) for code, tuples in values_by_word.items()}

Comment: File "CSV_dico_2.py", line 87, in <dictcomp>
    merged_values_by_word = {code:merge_values(tuples) for code, tuples in values_by_word.items()}
  File "CSV_dico_2.py", line 85, in merge_values
    return tuple(str(sum(int(v) for v in vs)) for vs in zip(*tuples))
  File "CSV_dico_2.py", line 85, in <genexpr>
    return tuple(str(sum(int(v) for v in vs)) for vs in zip(*tuples))
  File "CSV_dico_2.py", line 85, in <genexpr>
    return tuple(str(sum(int(v) for v in vs)) for vs in zip(*tuples))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' Des luxations '

Comment: @kely789456123 It seems that you have a string (`' Des luxations'`) in the tuples of int values. Have you checked that your orginal  `dico_lexique` is ok? Look for `' Des luxations'` in your csv file to check if the format is consistant.